# How to Play Streaming Audio in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, url, streaming, avplayer

I have searched relentlessly but with no luck.

I am simply trying to play streaming audio files (mp3) in my tableview (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) but their is no error in xcode but the mp3 wont play

Here is a snippet

```
NSString *urlstr = @"www.nosajsolomon.com/pull_up_to_mi_bumper.mp3";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem2 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem2];
[player play];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste your code of tableview row selection method.

Comment: have you check your tabeleviewdelegate are property assign to tableview object?